# Preventing other registered click event?

Tags: jquery

I have `p` element on page.

This `p`  has 2 binded clicks *(please leave it that way. I know there are other options.)*

```
 $('p').click (function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();  //<== not helping me as I thought it should
    alert('1');
    });

//...later on the same page...

    $('p').click (function ( ) {
    alert('2');
    });
```

I want that the first code will **prevent** the Second code from executing( **NOT** VIA FLAGS)

What is the most `elegant` way of doing this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
e.stopImmediatePropagation();
```

in the first function

edit: Demo to show hover is not affected:

http://jsfiddle.net/VEuRu/1/

Comment: What if i want to prevent Only the Click event and not the Hover event(e.g.) ?

Comment: Can you show the hover code? this shouldn't prevent hover event

Comment: jQuery says that it cancel all the attached handlers. But what if I want only Certain handlers to be deleted ?

Comment: It doesn't delete any handlers, it stops other click handlers from firing and prevents the click event propagating to higher elements in the dom. It should in this given context have no effect on any hover events.